# CentOS install R package RLumShiny failed

Tags: r, linux, shiny, centos, r-package

I tried to install the shiny related package RLumShiny on the server.
System Version: CentOS Linux release 8.1.1911 (Core)

I tried to use :

```
install.packages("RLumShiny")
```

Some errors were returned. But I can't find these errors now.

And then i tired to use :

```
wget https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/contrib/4.1/RLumShiny_0.2.2.tgz
R CMD INSTALL RLumShiny_0.2.2.tgz
R
library("RLumShiny")
```

The server reported an error:

```
>library(RLumShiny)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RLumShiny’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/shiny/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.1/terra/libs/terra.so':
  /home/shiny/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.1/terra/libs/terra.so: invalid ELF header
```

Then i tried :

```
>install.packages("RLumShiny")
Installing package into ‘/home/shiny/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
try open URL'https://mirror-hk.koddos.net/CRAN/src/contrib/RLumShiny_0.2.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 448539 bytes (438 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 438 KB

installing *source* package ‘RLumShiny’ ...
package ‘RLumShiny’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
using staged installation
R
inst
byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/shiny/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.1/terra/libs/terra.so':
  /home/shiny/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.1/terra/libs/terra.so: invalid ELF header
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImport -> loadNamespace -> library.dynam -> dyn.load
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘RLumShiny’
* removing ‘/home/shiny/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RLumShiny’
* restoring previous ‘/home/shiny/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RLumShiny’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpZxd0sL/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("RLumShiny") :
  installation of package ‘RLumShiny’ had non-zero exit status
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is clearly with the `terra` package. So the way to fix it would be to (re-) install that package first; perhaps after installing its system requirements (see the [repo](https://github.com/rspatial/terra)) perhaps with

`sudo dnf install gdal-devel proj-devel geos-devel sqlite-devel`